# lsyncd won't start at startup

Tags: startup, init-script, init, sysvinit

My os is mint 17.2

First off, when I start it with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lsyncd start
```

it starts.

But when I reboot my system it isn't started by default. How do I have it start at boot time?

I had previously had it as an Upstart job, but that wasnt working at startup either.

Here are my files/settings:

/etc/init.d/lsyncd

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          lsyncd
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: lsyncd daemon init script
# Description:       This script launches the lsyncd daemon.
### END INIT INFO

# Author: Ignace Mouzannar <ignace@enovance.com>

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="synchronization daemon"
NAME=lsyncd
DAEMON=/usr/bin/$NAME
CONFIG=/etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.conf.lua
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
DAEMON_ARGS="-pidfile ${PIDFILE} ${CONFIG}"
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
NICELEVEL=10

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

# Exit if config file does not exist
[ -r "$CONFIG" ] || exit 0

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6) to ensure that this file is present.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON \
        --test > /dev/null \
                || return 1
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE \
        --nicelevel $NICELEVEL --exec $DAEMON -- \
                $DAEMON_ARGS \
                || return 2
}

# 
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop()
{
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
        RETVAL="$?" 
        [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --exec $DAEMON
        [ "$?" = 2 ] && return 2
        # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.
        rm -f $PIDFILE
        return "$RETVAL"
}

#
# Function that sends a SIGHUP to the daemon/service
#
do_reload() {
        start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 1 --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
        return 0
}

case "$1" in
  start)
        log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_start
        case "$?" in
                0|1) log_end_msg 0 ;;
                2) log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
        ;;
  stop)
        log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_stop
        case "$?" in
                0|1) log_end_msg 0 ;;
                2) log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
        ;;
  status)
        status_of_proc $DAEMON $NAME && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
  restart|force-reload)
        log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_stop
        case "$?" in
          0|1)
                do_start
                case "$?" in
                        0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
                        1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
                        *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
                esac
                ;;
          *)
                # Failed to stop
                log_end_msg 1
                ;;
        esac
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac

:
```

/etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.conf.lua

```
    settings {
        nodaemon = false,
        statusFile = "/tmp/lsyncd.stat",
        statusInterval = 1,
        logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
        statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd-status.log"
}
sync {
        default.rsync,
    source = "/home/user/bin_pers/data",
    target = "/home/user/test",
        delay=0,
        rsync     = {
                perms = true,
                owner = true,
                archive = true
        }
}
```

empty files
/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log
/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd-status.log

Comment: The answer to your question depends from information that you haven't supplied: **what operating system** this is, and **what version** of that operating system.  [Edit] your question and put that in, otherwise answerers won't know whether your system can handle upstart jobs, systemd units, Debian flavours of System 5 `rc` scripts, Fedora flavours, BSD `rc` scripts, or several other possibilities; and what commands you need to use.

Comment: My os is mint 17.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, it was not starting because one of the rules involved an HD that was not mounted at started. Mounting then restarting lsyncd did the trick.